# QGIS / pyqgis error: wrapped C/C++ object of type QProgressBar has been deleted See log for more details

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, python-2.7, qgis-processing

I have this error when I run some of my python scripts.  It does not always occur.  It always happens at the END of the script, (all script actions finish!!)

I mainly need to fix it because it is annoying and it prevents me from stringing separate scripts together.

The traceback I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:/QGIS/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\GeoAlgorithm.py", line 203, in execute
            self.processAlgorithm(progress)
          File "C:/QGIS/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\script\ScriptAlgorithm.py", line 378, in processAlgorithm
            exec((script), ns)
          File "<string>", line 146, in <module>
        RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QProgressBar has been deleted
```

However the line it refers to does not seem to make any sense:

```
error2 = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(bufflayer, buffdef, "CP1250", None, "ESRI Shapefile")
```

Note that this and all of the python after this command always run just fine.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>Try adding the keyword `progress=None` to your call, i.e. 
error2 = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(bufflayer, buffdef, "CP1250", None, "ESRI Shapefile", progress=None)
I have not tested this in your case, but it worked for me when calling processing algorithms from script (`processing.runalg()`).</strike>

**Edit/summary:**

Apparently, the main culprit for wonky script behavior is the progress bar that comes with processing algorithms. Your best bet is to add the keyword `progress=None` to every `processing.runalg()` call you make. As an extra measure, check the source code of any algorithms you use in your script for calls *they* might make to other algorithms and add `progress=None` to those as well.

Comment: I'll give it a try!

Comment: No luck: it doesn't work for the QgsVectorFileWriter: it does not have that option.  I will look inside the process.runalg for that option though...

Comment: OK - your idea is CORRECT! but the implementation slightly off.

Comment: processing.runalg('script:scriptname', progress=None) DOES solve the problem!!!  Thanks so much!  You have saved me from a problem that has been plaguing me for 6 months!  Automation action!!

Comment: Nick, if you modify your answer I will mark it correct! -

Comment: Hmm... Turns out that this does not ALWAYS work - but it does most of the time! - Still searching!

Comment: Hey, glad I could be of some help. Eh, I don't think my answer really counts as correct, but I'll keep looking as well. I'll get back to you!

Comment: It seems to work in about 80% of cases.  I have not been able to track down the outliers yet.  The most important thing was to remove all of the progress bar calls from my script.  Now I only have one or two cases where it does not work.

Comment: Have you tried snooping around in the source code of the algorithms you use in your script? There is a possibility you're calling an algorithm which in turn calls another algorithm, but without the mighty `Progress=None`. [Here](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/12229) is a relevant bug report from a couple years ago. As you can see, the [fix](https://issues.qgis.org/projects/qgis/repository/revisions/14c858a0b1b56586902daaddb54840ac417f975c/diff/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/ConcaveHull.py) involved editing the ConcaveHull algorithm's call to another algorithm (qgis:delaunaytriangulation).

Comment: Everything I am calling is something that I wrote myself, so I know I am not calling another from inside.  (my top level scripts literally are just calls to my subscripts for automation purposes)  In any case - some of the errors were fixed by removing any and all calls to progress bar in the scripts.  I think I have managed to resolve all of the issues except for one and it is not a very critical item.  Thanks a lot for your help!